# Can we have AMP and PWA on same URL/page?

Tags: mobile-website, amp-html

We have already implemented our AMP page on our website - http://m.wishafriend.com/amp/
and we are also planning to implement PWA, so should we need to make a different page for PWA or is it possible to combine AMP and PWA on the same URL?

Answer (score 0):

@phpidz It is indeed possible to combine AMP and PWAs. There is a [good section](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/pwa-amp) in the [AMP Project website](https://www.ampproject.org/); it explains the context and the approaches you could follow.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is exactly pointing towards the integration of AMP and PWA. Now that we are aware of what is AMP and PWA, we need to proceed towards the next level of what is the difference between AMP and PWA and how to integrate the two to maximize the utilization of both the technologies. You can shift from AMP to PWA easily and also from PWA to AMP. First, PWA to AMP, you can use PWA as an app shell to serve AMP content. In this way you can utilize PWA’s versatility and AMP’s optimized performance, and can deliver a lighting-fast and rich user experience. Second, AMP to PWA, websites first accept the AMP technology and then shift to PWA. Here, you first accept AMP carousel then register in Service Worker of PWA. You can better understood this integration results better if you study a case study of Washington Post in Techmagnate blog. http://www.techmagnate.com/blog/what-difference-between-amp-pwa/ Here is the link for the detailed analysis of AMP PWA integration and also will be able to know the related factors of these two technologies for sure.